# should variable be released or not? iphone-sdk

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have the following piece of code from a book.

There is this function loadPrefs where the **NSString *userTimeZone** is being released before the end of the function.

Why? The string was not created with alloc and I assume that the stringForKey function returns an autoreleased NSString. Is this an error or am I missing something? Is it an error in the book? (I new into objective-C)

In the documentation for stringForKey the only thing it mentions is:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> The returned
>   string is immutable, even if the value
>   you originally set was a mutable
>   string.

The code:

```
- (void) loadPrefs {
    timeZoneName = DefaultTimeZonePref;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *userTimeZone = [defaults stringForKey: TimeZonePrefKey];
    if (userTimeZone != NULL)
        timeZoneName = userTimeZone;
    [userTimeZone release];
    show24Hour = [defaults boolForKey:TwentyFourHourPrefKey];
}
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Which book is that? Just so we can avoid it...

Comment: iPhone SDK Development. However it is a pretty good book, despite this code error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. There are two things wrong with this code: it's releasing the string from `stringForKey:` improperly, and it's **not** retaining `userTimeZone` when it assigns the value to an instance variable.

Here's a better attempt:

```
- (void) loadPrefs {
    [timeZoneName release]; // In case there was a previous value

    timeZoneName = DefaultTimeZonePref; // ASSUMPTION: DefaultTimeZonePref is a constant
    // And thus doesn't need retain/release.

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *userTimeZone = [defaults stringForKey: TimeZonePrefKey];
    if (userTimeZone != NULL) {
        timeZoneName = [userTimeZone retain];
    }

    show24Hour = [defaults boolForKey:TwentyFourHourPrefKey];
}
```

And don't forget to release `timeZoneName` in `dealloc`.

Comment: Doesn't retaining userTimeZone depend on how it's declared in the class definition?

Comment: It is defined as an instance variable. No property, no setter or getter. Just inside the interface **NSString *timeZoneName;**

Comment: Nathan: I think you're referring to the "assign", "retain", and "copy" options for a property declaration. In this case it's a simple instance variable so you don't have to worry about that.